# Source code failed to published via NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to publish NuGet with source code.

I added the source code into NuGet package like this (see right panel):

[image]

I published it to NuGet Gallery.

Then I opened Visual Studio 2013 and type this at the NuGet Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package MySqlBackup.NET
```

The Package Manager Console indicated that the installation of the package was successful:

[image]

However, I found that the source code files (the .cs files) was not added into the project, only the dependency of **MySql.Data** was added:

[image]

What steps did I miss?

Thanks you very much for your insights.

Comment: NuGet is not a hosting provider for source code.  It's a .NET package dependency manager intended for compiled binary distribution.  What you're doing may be workable but it's not the correct approach.  You're better off building out a CI process and publishing the outputs of that, much like @Aybe says below.  Symbol support is pretty good now in NuGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the way to go, in Nuget you would publish **symbols** that when the user debugs his code he can step through your source thanks to these symbols.

From the official docs :

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package

If you look at the [official docs](http://docs.nuget.org/), there is no chapter about publishing source code, just symbols.

Here's a tutorial on doing it :

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/easy-way-to-publish-nuget-packages-with.html

The common approach for publishing your source code would be on something such as [GitHub](https://github.com/).

Most of the time symbols will be sufficient if people just want to know what's happening under the hood. If they'd find a bug or would like to enhance the library they would either contact the author or fork that library.